# node.js log errors in file

Tags: node.js, file, logging

I'm trying to log errors to a file in node.js.
i tried winston:

```
winston= require('winston');
var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
transports: [
new (winston.transports.Console)({ level: 'error' }),
new (winston.transports.File)({ filename: 'error.log' })
]
});
```

I also tried console.error:

```
var log_file_err=
fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/error.log', {flags : 'a'});

var err_stdout = process.stderr;

console.error = function(d) { //
log_file_err.write(util.format(d) + '\n');
err_stdout.write(util.format(d) + '\n');
};
```

to generate an error i used:

```
function get_time(date)
{
     return date.getHours()+':'+date.getMinutes();
}
console.log(get_time(Date()));//instead of new Date()
```

i get no further errors(just the wanted undefined for Date()) but error.log stays empty."debug.log"(normal logging)where i use an overidden console.log works correctly.

Comment: no ideas? is this kind of error not written in the file because the app is crashing? if this the reason,how can i then log such errors to a file?

Comment: In your winston error log definition, if you pass in level: 'error' that will log fatal errors. I'm not sure how to capture all console.errors (still trying to figure that out)

Answer (score 5):

Finally i found a solution which works perfectly for me:

```
var log_file_err=fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/error.log',{flags:'a'});  

process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
console.log('Caught exception: ' + err);
log_file_err.write(util.format('Caught exception: '+err) + '\n');
});
```

Comment: This works okay for me.  Doesn't give me the most details about what went wrong but at least it's something.  Note that for this to work you need to define: `const fs = require('fs');` and `const util = require('util');`